# Apollo Graph QL - Router fails to start - Voyage II: Federating the Monolith

Tags: reactjs, apollo, router, apollo-federation

I am working on the course Voyage II: Federating the Monolith
https://www.apollographql.com/tutorials/voyage-part2/05-configuring-the-router

I have progressed along tot he point where we need to configure the router.

I have configured for config.yaml to be as follows:

headers:
all:
request:

propagate:
named: “Authorization”
include_subgraph_errors:
all: true # Propagate errors from all subgraphs
when trying to start up the router using the command below:
APOLLO_KEY=<APOLLO_KEY> APOLLO_GRAPH_REF=<APOLLO_GRAPH_REF> ./router --config config.yaml

I am getting the following error, please let me know how to address this. Up to this point my project works seamlessly. I went through the Authentication and Authorization project as well to ensure I did not miss any thing.

Have also converted the the subgraph to a supergraph:

./rover subgraph publish airlock-dwih0w@current
--schema ./monolith/schema.graphql
--name monolith
--routing-url http://localhost:4001
--convert

I have redone all of the tutorial Federating the Monolith - Voyager II and totally not sure what is wrong. Any inputs will be much appreciated as I seem to have hit a dead end.

./router --config config.yaml
Apollo Router v1.38.0 // (c) Apollo Graph, Inc. // Licensed as ELv2 (Apollo FAQ on Licensing under Elastic License v2 (ELv2) - Apollo GraphQL Docs)

⚠️ The Apollo Router requires a composed supergraph schema at startup. ⚠️

DO ONE:

Pass a local schema file with the ‘–supergraph’ option:

$ ./router --supergraph <file_path>

Fetch a registered schema from GraphOS by setting
these environment variables:

$ APOLLO_KEY=“…” APOLLO_GRAPH_REF=“…” ./router

For details, see the Apollo docs:
Setting up managed federation - Apollo GraphQL Docs

TESTING THINGS OUT?

Download an example supergraph schema with Apollo-hosted subgraphs:
$ curl -L https://supergraph.demo.starstuff.dev/ > starstuff.graphql
Run the Apollo Router in development mode with the supergraph schema:
$ ./router --dev --supergraph starstuff.graphql

Github repo for this project is https://github.com/mshah100/odyssey-voyage-II-server

Completed the tutorial 2 times.  Still stuck at the same step.